# Creation of energy

Tags: energy

When I'm learning about energy. There is a sentence leave me hang.

> Energy cannot be created nor be destroyed

So, if energy cannot be created, so how can we have energy in this world in the first place?

Comment: Possibly related:  [http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/what-is-energy-where-did-it-come-from](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3014/).

Comment: I will be looking at it

Comment: Look at the duplicate (and other related questions, e.g.: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138972/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137601/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145124/50583). All of the answer are essentially: It's a number. It doesn't "come" from anywhere.

Comment: Cough. Energy isn't just a number. Matter is made from it. The mass of a body is a measure of its energy-content.